# Using Select to dynamically create/delete table rows in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working with Jquery for the first time and I am supposed to use the Select tag to generate a table within a table. Since this is new to me, I've experimented with the syntax.  So far I've come up with the following code:

```
<select id="theSelect">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>


<input id="someInput"/>

<table id="mytable" border="1">
    <tr>
       <th>AAAAA</th>
       <th>BBBBB</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>CCCCC</td>
       <td>DDDDD</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $("#theSelect").change(function() {
        switch($(this).val())
         {
            case "foo":
                $("#someInput").val("hello");
                $("#mytable").append($("#blarg"))
                break;
            case "bar":
                $("#someInput").val("bye");
                //$("#mytable").remove($("#blarg"))
                $("#mytable").append($("#blah"))
                break;
            default:
                $("#someInput").val("really?");

            }

        }).change();
    </script>


    <div id="blarg">
    <tr><td>hello world</td><td></td></tr>
    </div>


    <div id="blah">
    <tr><td>goodbye world</td><td></td></tr>
    </div>
```

I get the someInput box value to change, and I manage to slowly modify the table values, but I haven't figured out yet how to only write 1 row at a time, depending on the value set by the select tag. I want to have blarg in the table when foo is selected and blah in the table when bar is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<table id="blarg" style="display: none">
    <tr>
        <td>hello world</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="blah" style="display: none">
    <tr>
        <td>goodbye world</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
$("#theSelect").change(function () {
    var tr;

    var $table = $("#mytable")
    $table.find('.select').remove();
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case "foo":
            $("#someInput").val("hello");
            tr = '#blarg';
            break;
        case "bar":
            $("#someInput").val("bye");
            tr = '#blah';
            break;
        default:
            $("#someInput").val("really?");

    }
    if(tr){
        $(tr).find('tr').clone().addClass('select').appendTo($table);
    }

}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/99A23/)

A cleaner solution can be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/99A23/5/)

Comment: Great thanks!!  

How would I make the "hello world" and "goodbye world" only appear inside and not outside the table in addition to what you've shown above?

Comment: @Lestat hide those elements using ` style="display: none"`